# CUSTOMVISION - Missing files when installing python packages

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I am trying to use the customvision SDK in python.
As it is explained on the customvision website, I run  `pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision`.
But I get a missing file error. Does someone could give me an example of :
*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\vision\customvision\prediction\models\**pycache**\**_custom_vision_prediction_client_enums.cpython-38.pyc**'*

Comment: You'd have to include the full traceback.

Comment: I am able to install custom vision package successfully in my environment. Can you please share a screenshot of the error you received and if possible the full traceback (as suggested above) so we can investigate further? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for trying to help but I fixed this problem yersteday.
In order to do that, I reinstalled python 3.8 and pip3, then I installed azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision==1.0.0 package.
However it didn't install the training package so I had to download it manually on Pypi.